# Trying to understand incrementing a counter in Array.reduce() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reduce

In the following Javascript [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) example, why does 'count' increment in the second reducer but not the first one?

I know I can just use the second example, but there was a case where I wanted to give a user name to some of the properties in the initial object.

```js
const data = [1,2,3,4];

data.reduce((accumulator) => {

    let { count } = accumulator;
    count++;
    console.log(accumulator);
    return accumulator;

}, { count: 0 });

/*
Returns:
{ count: 0 }
{ count: 0 }
{ count: 0 }
{ count: 0 } 
*/
```

```js
data.reduce((accumulator) => {

    accumulator.count++;
    console.log(accumulator);
    return accumulator;

}, { count: 0 });

/* 
Returns
{ count: 1 }
{ count: 2 }
{ count: 3 }
{ count: 4 } 
*/
```

Comment: Because you are creating a local variable called `count` in the first example, but not incrementing the `accumulator.count` value.

Comment: `let { count } = accumulator;` means you pull `count` out of `accumulator`.

Comment: this `{ count }` and `accumulator.count` is not the same.

Comment: Oh I see. Would ```let count = accumulator.count;``` be the same as ```let { count } = accumulator;```? So that means in the first example above I'm basically just creating a new local variable named ```count``` and assigning it a value of ```0``` on every loop?